# Give a numpy array of zeros and ones of varying length specific tags

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, tags

I'm coding in python. I want to give a numpy arrays, for example `[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]` a specific one-to-one tag in the form of a number, so that i can differentiate/search for them, using such a unique tag. In a paper I've found the idea for the following function:

```
def tag (v):
    val = 0
    for i in range(len(v)):
        val += math.sqrt(100 * (i + 1) + 3) * v[i]
    return val
```

that gives each array v a specific tag. Now i have a few problems:

1. I don't quite understand how one comes up such a formula
2. This algorith was posed for arrays with entries that can be all natural numbers, not only 1 and 0, so maybe it can be made more efficient for my purpose
3. The arrays in my program have differing lengths, so i would at best need an algorith that differs between those arrays, so that `[0, 0, 0]` gets a different tag from `[0, 0, 0, 0]`

Any solutions or ideas on how to topple this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an integer based on the zeros and ones in your array by considering it as a binary number. And for refuse of duplicate result for arrays with same items and different lengths you can sum the result with array's size.

```
In [74]: def create_flag(arr):
   ....:     size = arr.size
   ....:     return arr.dot(2**np.arange(size)[::-1]) + size
   ....:
```

Demo:

```
In [74]: arr = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
In [75]: create_flag(arr)
Out[75]: 379

In [76]: arr = np.array([0, 0])

In [77]: create_flag(arr)
Out[77]: 2

In [78]: arr = np.array([1, 0])

In [79]: create_flag(arr)
Out[79]: 4

In [81]: arr = np.array([0])

In [82]: create_flag(arr)
Out[82]: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not hash the array?

```
# use arr.tostring() if tobytes is not present
hash(arr.tobytes())
```

This will be a signed integer.  If numeric properties related to the numbers are needed, that consider how large the maximal sum of your array is going to be.  Add the sum of your array to the hash value raised to a power of 10 large enough to avoid dropping bits of your hash's uniqueness (other than the sign, which is necessary to preserve sort order):

```
sum(arr)*10**64 + abs(hash(arr.tobytes())) 
# now your tag will be sortable by value and unique
```

This second trick will only work in python3 or later, where integers are unbound.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the binary conversion method that @Kasramvd shows above, but believe the function fails for the following use case:

```
arr1 = np.array( [0,0] ) # create_flag returns '2'
arr2 = np.array( [1] ) # create_flag returns '2'
```

Since you cannot blindly add the size to the exponential result. IMHO, you could use a 2D matrix (of length len(arrays) with the array size and the binary values as your lookups. In the end you have something like this:

```
# Modified binary value function
def get_binary_value(arr):
    return arr.dot(2**np.arange(arr.size)[::-1])

# Then store
binVal = get_binary_value( my_array )
arrLen = len( my_array )
mat[arrLen][binVal] = my_array # mat is of numpy 2D array and pre-defined dimensions
```

This has a few obvious caveats:

1. Utilizes an array (matrix) instead of a singular value. There are many methods for creating an unique value from seeds if you need that.
2. It is inefficient as the array size and number of 1's increase since we are using the decimal value as a key (meaning array needs to be of equal/greater length).